# FileNotFoundException with Nashorn

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am playing a little bit with nashorn and I did a form and a servlet but I can´t not get the script file.
I have this code. The calls to the servlet are working well, as well the hello world message.

```
engine.eval(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Gabriel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebApplication1\\src\\java\\paquete\\script.js"));
```

Given the absolute path works perfectly... but i want to give the relative path

```
    HttpSession sesion=request.getSession();
    String submit=request.getParameter("submit");
            ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        try {
            System.out.println("PATH:"+request.getContextPath());
            engine.eval(new FileReader("src/java/paquete/script.js"));
        } catch (ScriptException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Servlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

            Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;

    switch(submit){
    case "Login":
            try {
                engine.eval("print('Hello World!');");
            } catch (ScriptException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Servlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
                break;
}
```

I have my script file in the same place where the servlet is.

Gives me this trace

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\java\paquete\script.js (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:87)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at paquete.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks advanced for your help

Comment: Would you provide more details on how you run it and what the outputs are?  Thinking that it is one of two things; the working directory is not what you think it is, or that you are running under a security that is preventing you from reading the file.

Comment: check if the file exist in src\java\paquete\

Comment: it exists in that folder

Comment: But that folder is not in the "current directory" of the web container via that path.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before, and the way I solve it is to  evaluate a "load" javascript funtion.
So, instead of doing

```
engine.eval(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Gabriel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebApplication1\\src\\java\\paquete\\script.js"));
```

you can try doing

```
engine.eval("load('src/java/paquette/script.js')");
```

and use Invocable engine after.

Hopefully it helps !